# Not sure if I need to use .append or something else

Tags: python, arrays, discord.py

````
random.shuffle(Players)
Terrorists = Players[:amount]
if Terrorists in Players:
    Players.remove(Terrorists)
msg = f"```Terrorists:\n{chr(10).join(t.name for t in Terrorists)}```"
for t in Terrorists:
    await t.send(msg)
````

Both `Players` and `Terrorists` are arrays and I'm not sure if I need to add `.append` somewhere. All I know is the code as a whole doesn't work and this is the only issue I'm think there might be. I'm happy to provide more information if needed and would apricate any help as this is my first 'big' project.

Comment: What kind of array are they, numpy arrays? `.append()` is used for lists, not arrays.

Comment: `Terrorists` is a slice of `Players`. `in list` tests whether something is a single element, not a slice, so that will never be true.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. You just set `Terrorists` to a part of `Players`, why do you need the `if` test?

Comment: If you want to eliminate the end of the list, simply do `Players = Players[amount:]`

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information and confusion between arrays and lists as I thought they were the same thing, I'm still very new to this hence why the code my not be the best written. The code is trying to randomly select a certain number of players from the Players list to become terrorists. So it picks the players then removes them from the list so that later code can do a similar thing for a different role. It's then meant to message the player(s) that they are the terrorist and if applicable who the others are as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the slice that you just assigned to `Terrorists`, assign the other slice of the list back to `Players`.

```
Terrorists = Players[:amount]
Players = Players[amount:]
```

Comment: Now giving me this error at the end of the new line. IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Then fix your indentation to match properly. If you got rid of the `if`, you have to move the following line over.